# How to display Arabic message from settings.setting file

Tags: c#

I want to display some messages which will come from settings.setting file. But when i paste arabic text instead displayfrom right to left, it comes left to right. Please give solution

Comment: Make a console application program which reproduce this problem and paste it here. Probably is my mistake but I don't even understand you ! Also Read the FAQ how you should ask a question !

Comment: @mybirthname: Are you sure the console supports bi-directional text? This sounds like something UI-toolkit-specific (-> OP, please add a tag that states the UI toolkit you are using).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper not I'm not sure. Probably because of that I was confused.